# Why does `main` end with `ret` and not `ret 4`?

Tags: c, disassembly, calling-convention

Consider the following empty C program (the standard guarantees that the compiler does an implicit `return 0`):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {}
```

You can add any logic into this function that manipulates `argc` and `argv`. Yet, when `main` finishes, its assembly code will just do a simple `ret` instead of `ret 4`. I am expecting to see a `ret 4` because in my mind `main` is the callee of some other function and therefore must clean up its two arguments from the stack: and int and a pointer to char array. Why does it not  do so?

Comment: [Calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Comment: main is *__cdecl* - so stack must adjust caller. must be `ret`. and even if it be `__stdcall` will be `ret 2*(sizeof(void*)` - so `ret 8` or `ret 16` but never `ret 4`

Comment: Nitpick: `argv` is a pointer to pointer, not a pointer to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most compilers choose to have the caller clean the arguments from the stack; a tradition that dates from early C compilers and handling number of arguments.  At the call-site, the compiler knows how many it pushed, so it is trivial for it to adjust the stack.

Also, note that historically main can be specified with 0-3 (arge) arguments.  Again, the caller (eg. _start) can just provide 3 and let the implementor choose.